# WebRTC remoteVideo Element endlessly loading

Tags: webrtc

Any idea where the problem might be?  The localVideo element works fine, but all I get, in both computers, for the remoteVideo element,  is this (endlessly circling/loading), with...

- [networkState](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_networkstate.asp) `2 = NETWORK_LOADING - browser is downloading data`
- [readyState](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_readystate.asp) `0 = HAVE_NOTHING - no information whether or not the audio/video is ready`

[image]

[image]
I've checked everything:

✔️ Each Peer-Connection (pc) has the correct **remoteSDP** that came from the other Peer's Offer-or-Answer.

✔️ The **remoteVideo element** has . . .

- `Autoplay == true`
- `Muted == false`
- `Paused == false`
- `Disabled == false`

✔️ **ICE** seemed to work out, because each PC has . . .

- `iceConnectionState: "new"`
- `iceGatheringState: "complete"`

✔️ The **last command** in my code is . . .

- `remoteVideoElement.srcObject = e.streams[0];` (triggered by a previously-declared `pc1.addEventListener('track', gotRemoteStream);` )

✔️ Nothing happens when I open up the console, and try to **manually** attach the PC's remoteStream to the video element, like this:

- `remoteVideo.srcObject = pc1.getRemoteStreams()[0];`

**Here below are my two combined `console.log()`s:**

The Offerer's activity is on the ⏪left; the Answerer's activity is on the right⏩.  `@Answerer` means the message is being sent ***TO*** the Answerer.

```````````````````````````````````````````````````
Offerer(pc1) . . . . . . . . . . . . Answerer(pc2)
``````````````````````````````````````````````````
Requesting local stream
Received local stream
Created local peer connection object pc1
Added local stream to pc1
pc1 createOffer start
-----------------2-----------------Offer, then SDP
2_____PC1_signalingState_____ stable
setLocalDescription complete
2.5_____PC1_signalingState_____ have-local-offer
--3--------------------------------
onOfferSendItToOtherPc()
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . message: @Answerer SDP-Offer:{"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 1919269707352669653 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS 2qzHy5PolwyGALtwc39fuVJT4aGMaOdSJP8d......"}
-------------------------------4---
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Requesting local stream
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . message: @Answerer ICE-Cand
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . message: @Answerer ICE-Cand
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . message: @Answerer ICE-Cand
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . message: @Answerer ICE-Cand
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . message: @Answerer ICE-Cand:null
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Received local stream
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Created local peer connection object pc2
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Added local stream to pc2
❌PROBLEM HERE? (NO ANSWER YET!). . received remote stream  
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . setRemoteDescription complete
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 4.5_____PC2_signalingState_____ have-remote-offer
----------------------------5------
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . setLocalDescription complete
--------------------------------6--
 . . .❗ ANSWER SENT HERE! . . . . . onAnswerSendItToOtherPc()
message: @Offerer SDP-Answer:{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 4846855406168784799 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS w2GnbUcp9SIA2ItZwAf9BIH9gBppgNJh4zju......"}
message: @Offerer ICE-Cand
pc1 received remote stream
setRemoteDescription complete
7. Answerer ==================== setRemoteDescription =======================
message: @Offerer ICE-Cand
message: @Offerer ICE-Cand:null
```````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ICE seemed to work out, because each PC has . . .
>
> ```
> iceConnectionState: "new"
> ```

If iceConnectionState is still new then ICE did *not* work.

That it is still new and not even checking suggests no remote ice candidates have been added to the connection. [This blog post](https://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/) explains the methodology of using chrome://webrtc-internals to figure out why that happens.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! After much battling, I figured out that my SPECIFIC ICE-error was that I was trying to add trickle-ICE-candidates, before either of the SDP-Offers was set.